# Is -cund a sufix?

Tags: suffixes

I saw words *fecund, jocund, rubicund* end with *-cund*.

Is *-cund* a suffix and what does it mean?

Comment: I think I'd be right in saying that if we accept *-cund* is indeed a suffix, most likely every such word could also accept *-cundity*. But according to [OneLook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3Fcundity&ls=a) there are less than a dozen such words, so it's not exactly a "productive" suffix.

Comment: By the way, you should really learn some Latin, you'll love it! So many things in English, the Romance languages, and basically anything in the European culture sphere will make so much more sense!

Comment: @Cerberus: Although I am not studying linguistics, I find I have felt in love it. I wish I could learn Latin some time in the future. Now I have to focus on English exams for applying to graduate schools, and study for some other areas to make a living.   What references (books and websites) would you recommend for Latin, Greek, linguistics, ..., for better understanding English?

Comment: @Tim: Oh I honestly wouldn't know, I learned all those things from books written mostly in Dutch...good luck with everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-cund (-cundus) is indeed a Latin suffix in words like *jocund*, *fecund*, *rubicund*, *secundus*, *iracund* and *gesithcund*, meaning *of that kind* or *inclining to*.

Comment: Exactly. The *Oxford Latin Dictionary* says "capacity or inclination".

Comment: The suffix in *gesithcund* is not related to the one in the Latin words. Wiktionary says Old English *-cund* "born," found in compounds like *eorlcund* and *gesiþcund,* comes from Proto-Indo-European **ǵn̥h₁tós* "born." The latin equivalent would be *(g)nātus.* Latin *-cundus,* on the other hand, is of unclear etymology. I've asked a question about it on Latin SE: [Unde “-cundus”?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/805)